# Profiling tools for Sharepoint 2010 web part .NET code

Tags: web-part, asp.net, tools, profiling

We are working on a pretty large scale project having large number of custom web parts with substantial amount .NET code working on Sharepoint server object model and the like.

The normal profiling techniques and tools seems inadequate, hence wished to know if there is a tool or combination of some tools to generate profile report that can be used as a starting point for effecting improvements.

MS Tools such as VSAspNetPerfmon and others are already reviewed and they seem to provide more of high level information.

Thanks,
Samir P

Answer (score 1):

1) Have you come across the Developer Dashboard in SharePoint 2010 - http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2009/10/28/using-the-developer-dashboard-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx

When the dashboard is turned on, you will find information about the controls, queries and execution time that occur as part of the page rendering process.

2) Visual Studio also does Performance Profiling for SharePoint 2010. Please visit [this blog](http://blogs.infosupport.com/performance-profiling-a-sharepoint-2010-solution/) for detailed approach on how this could be achieved.

3) Also look into the ANTS Performance profiler tool from Redgate - http://www.red-gate.com/support/Knowledgebase/ANTS_Profiler/AP4SharePoint.pdf

Comment: what about sandboxed solutions, we're talking about .NET code that interacts with Sharepoint server object model.

Comment: The Developer dashboard is indeed intended for .Net code throughout your SharePoint application. If you have custom code, insert it into `using (SPMonitoredScope GetListsBtnScope = new
     SPMonitoredScope("Your Custom code"))` . Please read through the entire article about Developer Dashboard. It should be a good fit for your requirement and it comes out of the box.

Comment: For sandboxed solution, the logs won't appear on ULS/ Dev Dashboard as per MSDN article. Please correct me if this is not the case, and provide a work around if there is one.

Answer (score 0):

[dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) is the one of the best profiling tools. It can profile ASP.NET applications.

Comment: I have used dotTrace, but as you can see here we're talking about Sharepoint server object model, which will require tool to have the capabilities of analyzing from that viewpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/)

Comment: Thanks, but seems like it's more of a code quality analysis tool. I am looking for something that offers performance and memory profiling, code quality improvements could be a good to have.